# I just want to rename a bunch of files with the same extension to the name of the folder that they are in, in python. how can I do it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, rename

Folder
|
-----subfolder
|
------ files

The rough map of what I'm trying to describe. The are files with a certain extension and same name among other files. I just want them to be copied to another directory and renamed by the name of subfolder they are in, in way that the original files remain intact.
but couldn't figure it out how? like I could manage to get a copy of them in another directory but that would make a mess, because they are named the same.

I used this code:

```
for folders, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(source_folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith("{}".format(extension)):
           shutil.copy(os.path.join(folders, filename), destination_folder)
```

Comment: Break it into subproblems: "How to traverse a folder recursively", "How to rename a file". There are answers for both of these on this site

Comment: It would help if you tell us what the folder would look like after the files have been renamed